# Reading a file into a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c

How can write this file

```
5 
Llewellyn Mark 
1 15 19 26 33 46 
Young Brian 
17 19 33 34 46 47 
Cazalas Jonathan 
1 4 9 16 25 36 
Siu Max 
7 19 34 46 47 48 
Balci Murat 
5 10 17 19 34 47`
```

into a dynamically allocated array

```
typedef struct KnightsBallLottoPlayer{
char firstName[20];
char lastName[20];
int  numbers[6]
} KBLottoPlayer;
```

the first row of the file indicates the number of individual names and number sets.

I have tried to use the below code to dynamically allocate the memory needed for n people using the struct but I am lost on how to read the information in, following the first read to get the n amount of users.

```
  int n; 
  FILE *fin;
  fin = fopen("text.in","r");

  if (fin == NULL){
   printf("Error: No File!");
  }

  fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);
  printf("%d",n); //reads file correctly

  struct KnightsBallLottoPlayer *p = calloc(sizeof(KBLottoPlayer), n);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate many times over, but I will have to find the appropriate link. Works the same every time. Read the 1st line into a `size_t` (or `int`), say variable `n`. Then allocate (and validate) that number of `KBLottoPlayer` (e.g. `KBLottoPlayer *players = malloc (n * sizeof *players); if (players == NULL) { /* handle error */ };` then you can use `fscanf` (which will skip the intervening `'\n'`) to fill each struct -- and always validate the return of `fscanf` to insure your read succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

While the basic premise of the question has been answered many times, each implementation varies just enough based on the data file format, it makes it difficult to find an exact duplicate.

Continuing from the comment, the approach is the same, but the details of how you handle the read will vary based on your input file format and struct members. When you are given a first line specifying how many of what comes next you will need to read, the easiest way to handle storage for your array of stuct is simply to allocate storage for that many struct with `malloc` (you can use `calloc` if you wish to zero all bytes at the time of allocation). While you can use a VLA (Variable Length Array), it is just as easy to allocate for `'n'` struct.

The read in your case becomes the challenge. You are needing to read data from two separate lines into a single struct. While I would generally suggest `fgets` to read each line and then call `sscanf` to parse the data (which you could still do here), `fscanf` with its format string will simplify the process by allowing you to read both lines of data in a single call ***if, and only if*** you already know the number of elements in your member array (your `numbers`). In your case it is fixed at `6`, so as long as that is the case, you can take the simple route.

When reading with any input function (and especially the `scanf` family of functions), you **must** validate the return of the function to insure there was a successful conversion for each *conversion specifier* in your *format string*. The `scanf` family of functions return the number of successful number of conversions that took place (or EOF if end-of-file was encountered before a conversion took place). Since `fscanf` will ignore the intervening `'\n'`, you can read both lines of your data for each struct with the following:

```
        int rtn = fscanf (fp, "%19s %19s %d %d %d %d %d %d", 
                    players[i].firstName, players[i].lastName,
                    &players[i].numbers[0], &players[i].numbers[1],
                    &players[i].numbers[2], &players[i].numbers[3],
                    &players[i].numbers[4], &players[i].numbers[5]);
```

You would validate that a successful read occurred before you increment `i` with something like the following:

```
        if (rtn == EOF)         /* validate fscanf return not EOF */
            break;
        else if (rtn != 8) {    /* check for matching or input failure */
            fputs ("error: matching or input failure occurred.\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else        /* all struct values read, increment counter */
            i++;
```

You place that in a loop and loop until your index reaches the number of elements you were told to read (or `EOF` occurs) and you are essentially done (don't forget to close the file you are reading from and `free` the memory you allocate). A short example putting it altogether could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct KnightsBallLottoPlayer {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int  numbers[6];
} KBLottoPlayer;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t i = 0, n = 0;
    KBLottoPlayer *players = NULL;  /* pointer to players */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fscanf (fp, "%zu", &n) != 1) {  /* read first value into size_t */
        fputs ("error: invalid format - 'n'\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate array of 'n' KBLottoPlayer */
    if ((players = malloc (n * sizeof *players)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-players");
        return 1;
    }

    while (i < n) { /* read until 'n' struct worth of data read */
        int rtn = fscanf (fp, "%19s %19s %d %d %d %d %d %d", 
                    players[i].firstName, players[i].lastName,
                    &players[i].numbers[0], &players[i].numbers[1],
                    &players[i].numbers[2], &players[i].numbers[3],
                    &players[i].numbers[4], &players[i].numbers[5]);
        if (rtn == EOF)         /* validate fscanf return not EOF */
            break;
        else if (rtn != 8) {    /* check for matching or input failure */
            fputs ("error: matching or input failure occurred.\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else        /* all struct values read, increment counter */
            i++;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    if (i < n) {    /* validate 'n' value read or reduce 'n' */
        fputs ("error: less than all data read.\n", stderr);
        n = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* output results */
        printf ("%s %s\n%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", 
                players[i].firstName, players[i].lastName,
                players[i].numbers[0], players[i].numbers[1],
                players[i].numbers[2], players[i].numbers[3],
                players[i].numbers[4], players[i].numbers[5]);

    free (players); /* don't forget to free the memory you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the `%19s` in `fscanf` prevents reading more than 19-characters (plus the *nul-terminating character* for both the `firstName, lastName` variables to prevent writing beyond their array bounds)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/players_struct <dat/playerdata.txt
Llewellyn Mark
1 15 19 26 33 46
Young Brian
17 19 33 34 46 47
Cazalas Jonathan
1 4 9 16 25 36
Siu Max
7 19 34 46 47 48
Balci Murat
5 10 17 19 34 47
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. There are many different ways to do this and using a VLA would avoid the allocation, but this is probably on par with any of the simple approaches. There are always additional validations you can use, but the above covers the salient ones.

Comment: When an errors occurs and with production code, I have found it invaluable to  print the offending line number and/or line.  Hence using `fgets()` to read lines (and form line count)  is a suggested alternative to this fine answer.

Comment: First off. Thank you for the amazing response. I do have some followup questions.
In the second set of checks validating that the code loaded. I get the error Invalid format - n. What is the purpous of this check?
Thank you again!

Comment: @Rando - that check is a check on the first line, that it contains an integer number that is being scanned as `size_t` into `n`. If you are on an older windows (like Win7/VS10, etc..) it doesn't recognize `size_t`. Change all `size_t` to `unsigned` and `%zu` to `%u`. That check should not fail as long as the first value in the file is a number.